# Android app ported to BlackBerry 10 fails after enabling proguard

Tags: android, blackberry, proguard, porting

I have an existing android app that i'm modifying to work on BlackBerry 10. Currently BB10 will run APK's without requiring conversion to Blackberry Bar files but I found parts of the app would not work when proguard was enabled. Namely, making http/s calls to my server. In debug mode everything worked smoothly.

I found no way to troubleshoot this because unless you are building your android project with Ant (instead of gradle), then there's no way to run your project with proguard enabled and step through the code to see the failure point.

Answer (score 0):

After much google research and testing, I found that if I added the line
**-donotoptimize** in the proguard rules file, proguard would obfuscate as required but my http calls went through. The downside however is that the apk file size is larger, due to lack of optimization.

I've posted this in case it helps someone facing the same problem in future.